# return_sequences in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

In Keras, model.add(LTSM(units=xx, return_sequences = yy, input_shape=zz), When setting the return_sequences to true, does it mean to have/enable the arrow circled in blue, and not have/disable the arrow circled in red? and vice versa when return_sequences set to false?
Note the picture comes from this page: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/12/fundamentals-of-deep-learning-introduction-to-lstm/ under '4. Architecture of LSTMs'[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the circle in blue is the essence of LSTM and it will never be disabled or you will not have a rnn/lstm at all. That arrow means that whatever the value you get from the last rnn/lstm cell, you will pass it to the next rnn/lstm cell and it will be processed together with the next input. The only difference between rnn and lstm is just that a simple rnn does not have that blue-circled arrow, only the black arrow below while lstm has that arrow as a gate for short/long term memory.

Second, for return_sequences, it is typically used for stacked rnn/lstm, meaning that you stack one layer of rnn/lstm on top of another layer VERTICALLY, not horizontally. Horizontal rnn/lstm cells represent processing across time, while vertical rnn/lsm cells means stacking one layer across another layer.

When you set it to false, it means that only the last cell (horizontally) will have that red_circled arrow while all other cells (in the same layer) will have that red_circled arrow disabled so you will only pass one piece of information from all that horizontal layer (that is the information passed by the last cell in that layer).

Conversely, when you set it to true, all cells from that horizontal layer will have that red-circled arrow abled, and will pass information to the layer stacked top of it. It means that if you want to stack one rnn/lstm layers on top of another, you need to set it to true.

Lastly, for more information you can refer to this book. It has great explanation for this return_sequences option: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/

Comment: Thank you! Very good information! I have a few follow up questions:
- How do you stack the layer veritically and horizontally?
Is this vertically? 
model.add(LSTM(units=xx, return_sequences=True, input_shape=zz))
model.add(LSTM(units=xx2))
- what's the benefit of stacking vertically vs horizontally?

Comment: Yes this is vertically. For "horizontally", it simply mean a processing across the time. So there is nothing you need to do for stacking rnn/lstm horizontally. It just refers to the fact that rnn and lstm process and takes input across time (in each timestep), and it is the essence of recurrent neural network. For "vertically", it is the same as you stacking one dense layer on top of another, it just take the inputs from the layer below and process it again. The benefit of stacking vertically is the same as you stack another dense layer, it just makes it able to fit more complex patterns.

Comment: Thank you! in what kind of scenario would you set return_sequences=True versus false? (if you already have multiple vertical layers)

Comment: In all kinds of scenario as long as there is another rnn/lstm layer on top of it. If you do not set it to be true in the lower layer the top rnn/lstm layer would throw an error message.